# Find the structure of an Active Directory

Tags: macos, active-directory

I'm using an AD to retrieve data about people in a company and it will really help me to find the structure of the AD, like a tree or something.

Is there any way to find it?

I'm working on a Mac.

**EDIT**

I will try to give more information about what I am doing exactly:

I'm using JS to retrieve data situated on an AD at which I'm connecting with credentials that my company gave me.
My goal is to retrieve all the users from this AD but it looks like the structure of the AD is kind of weird. So it will help me a lot to see how groups are organized!

Comment: Just a small point: structure of AD is a bit unclear; can you exactly highlight what do you need - architecture of domain / OU arrangements within a domain / user-management within a company, ... and so on! Also, are you sure you'd b using a MacOS for this, and not a Windows based OS (its like travelling in water on your motorbike)?

Comment: For now i'm using MacOS because i'm only discovering how AD works, but after it will be different.

Comment: Sorry to say, but the question is still unclear to me. What is JS? What do you mean when you say `My goal is to retrieve all the users from this AD but it looks like the structure of the AD is kind of weird. So it will me a lot to see how groups are organised` - are you talking about hierarchy of the domain of whose user-credential you've been provided with? If the structure would be weird, I think the hierarchy would make no difference in result!

Comment: Maybe it because of my few knowledge on the subject that is making my request unclear. An AD is a structure of Data is that right ? Users are sort by Groups, and Groups can be part of other Groups, my goal is to have something like a view of all this. So i dont know what you mean by hierarchy but maybe it is what i'm looking for. 
PS : JS was for JavaScript because i thought maybe this will help understand.